# equinox jetty NoClassDefFoundError: SslContextFactory

Tags: osgi, classnotfound

i have a osgi project in indigo ide, which use equinox 3.7.0 + jetty 7.5.1, now i upgrade ide to juno, which contain equinox 3.8.0 + jetty 8.1.3, so,

the tragedy go on: 
    when compiling, complain accesible restrictation on SslContextFactory's methods, i resolved it by editing it's access rules in build path. 
    when running, have a error, say

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory
```

now i have no idea, thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

The access rules are there for a reason.... by hiding the build-time error, you just made the runtime error appear.

The proper solution is to import the package `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl` in your bundle.

If you use a tool such as [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org) then these `Import-Package` dependencies will be detected and generated automatically.